# Reading environment variable in command alias causes evaluating it?

Tags: command-line, shell, environment-variables, msys

I have simple alias for writing to log files (this is what I have in my .profile file):

```
logtee() {
    ${TEST_LOG_FOLDER:?"empty_log_folder"}
    tee -a $TEST_LOG_FOLDER/$1
}
```

I'm reading the folder from environment variable (so this variable holds value similar to 'd/my/logs'). However, when I try using this alias by executing `echo 'this is reading path from env.variable!' | logtee whatever.log` it works, but the output is: `sh.exe": /d/my/log/path: is a directory`. 
Did I do something wrong? Why does reading environment variable evaluate it? I suspect it have something to do with a fact that it's an alias, because in usual .sh script similar code works without any issues

 P.S. I'm using msysgit on Windows 7, may be that's the problem?

Comment: What do you mean "it's an alias"?  I don't see any aliasing here (have you exported the function inside one of your scripts; e.g. ".profile" or ".bashrc", etc.).  Also, why do you have "sh.exe" in the output?  Are you running on Windows or Linux?  And, finally, what is the output of `echo $TEST_LOG_FOLDER`.

Comment: @jehad I'm sorry I wasn't clear - updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of your function is indeed evaluating it. You could replace it by:

```
echo ${TEST_LOG_FOLDER:?"empty_log_folder"} > /dev/null
```

A better solution would be:

```
[ -d "${TEST_LOG_FOLDER:?'empty_log_folder'}" ] && \
```

The best solution is not to use a separate line, so the whole function becomes:-

```
logtee() {
    tee -a "${TEST_LOG_FOLDER:?'empty_log_folder'}/$1"
}
```

Note that I have changed the quoting, in case there is a space in `$TEST_LOG_FOLDER` or `$1`.